# CSV duplicate row method not finding output file

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

I'm trying to do something very simple, use more_itertools to output unique rows from CSV File 1 to CSV File 2 as an iterative process over many CSV files.  However, I receive the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'first_file.csv'
```

Here's the code in question.  I am iterating over a list object called "newCsvFileList" containing many CSV files.  I am using the more_itertools library for this and import the unique_everseen method from it at the beginning of the script.

```
outDir = filepath + "\\final_tables"

for i in newCsvFileList:
    outCsv = os.path.join(outDir, i)
    if not os.path.exists(outDir):
        try:
            os.makedirs(outDir)
        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
    with open(i, 'r') as f, open(outCsv, 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.writelines(unique_everseen(f))
```

The outDir directory is being created successfully, but obviously outCSV file is not being created.

Comment: It doesn't find the _input_ file (not the basename in the error). that's simply because the file isn't in the current directory from which the script is run!!

Comment: Oh jeez.  Tired eyes.  I fixed it by including a parameter called `oldCsv = os.path.join(inDir, i)` and now it works.  Thanks! :-)  Hey, no need to downvote the question though, who knows who it might help out sometime.

Comment: I'm really not sure that the question would help someone else. It's more like a typo. Anyway, glad that it helped you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd post the fix nonetheless for thoroughness.

```
outDir = filepath + "\\final_tables"
inDir = filepath + "\\input_tables"

for i in newCsvFileList:
    oldCsv = os.path.join(inDir, i)  # This is what was missing
    outCsv = os.path.join(outDir, i)
    if not os.path.exists(outDir):
        try:
            os.makedirs(outDir)
        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
    with open(i, 'r') as f, open(outCsv, 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.writelines(unique_everseen(f))
```

Comment: why not using `os.path.join` for `outDir` and `inDir` too? `outDir = os.path.join(filepath,"final_tables")`